# Passar parametros de uma classe Adapter para uma outra activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, android-adapter

preciso da ajuda de voce, crie uma classe chamanda ItensAdapter que cria um listView com os dado do banco, até ai blz, agora preciso capturar estes dados em uma outra activity para inserir as quantidades destes itens vou postar o codigo.

```
public class ItensAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context ctx;
    private List<buscaItens> lista;

    String qtdItens;

    public ItensAdapter(Context ctx2, List<buscaItens> list2){

        ctx = ctx2;
        lista = list2;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return lista.size();
    }

    @Override
    public buscaItens getItem(int i) {
        return lista.get(i);
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        View v = null;

        if(view == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)ctx).getLayoutInflater();
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.espelho, null);
        }else{

            v = view;
        }  buscaItens p = getItem(i);



        TextView item = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item);
        Spinner quantidade = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.quantidade);
        TextView codigo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.codigo);

        ArrayAdapter qtd = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(ctx,R.array.conectores, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        item.setText(p.getItem()+":");
        quantidade.setAdapter(qtd);
        codigo.setText(p.getCodigo());


        return v;



    }
}
```

Como faço para enviar cada item da `ListView` para outra activity?

```
EXEMPLO DO LISTVIEW:
item1-------Codigo1------Spinner com quantidades.
item2-------Codigo2------Spinner com quantidades.
```

Quero pegar estes 3 itens em outra activity.

Comment: Contextos diferentes

Comment: mesmo contexto, a unica coisa que muda é que você tem que ativar o onclick do seu item da lista passando o intent dentro

Comment: O contexto até pode ser diferente mas a solução continua a ser a mesma.

Comment: Show galera vou tentar, lembrando que não vai haver um evento de clique, o usuario vai escolher os valores e varios spinner e esse valores serão coletados.